# Wordpress Media Import, images not in Media Library

Tags: media-library, import

I have performed two imports using the WP Importer plugin, one of a custom post type and the 2nd of the Media Library. Both imports appear to work, on fact a second attempt to import the Media Library gives "File Exists" messages.

In the individual post the featured image is showing, with thumbnail, with the correct, updated URL.  In cPanel, all the images are in place with correct folder structure and thumbnails

But in the media library, there is nothing showing.

Comment: how did you perform the media library import?

Comment: Using the Wordpress Export / Import

Comment: I exported the CPT and Media from the old site and then performed twp imports into the new site, with Import Attachment checked on both

Comment: you mean you used a WXR import/export with the WP importer plugin? I ask because the word "import" could mean many different things, e.g. you used WP DB All in One Importer, or you FTP'd the files, etc. Also, when you say the images do not appear, do you mean the attachments are there but have broken thumbnails/images? Or do you mean the media library is empty? Be as specific as possible, even if it seems like you're stating the obvious. Also is your old site accessible from the new site via the network without DNS shenanigans?

Comment: OK, the WP native Import. The Media Library is empty. The individual posts have the correct Featured Image, complete with thumbnail and correct updated URL. Yes, you're right I should have said 'native importer'.

Comment: do you have any `pre_get_posts` filters in the codebase? And is it just the media WP Admin page, or is it also happening in the modal dialogs in post editors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate that 'non-standard' behaviour doesn't have an easy answer. No plugins, default theme though it is multisite. And it's in the modal dialogues although, as I say, the existing Featured Image thumbnail is present.

Comment: and those instances where it shows the image, is the URL for that site or the old site? Have you checked the attachment posts exist in the database for the newly imported files? Is the old site/URL accessible via the internet from the new site/target?

Comment: "correct updated URL" the new site. The attachments are in the database but with the parent post set to 0 (even though they are visible in the individual posts)